# Oracle trigger failed -ORA-04098

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, ora-04098

I have a table for which i have written a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ac01_control_trigg
AFTER INSERT ON ac1_control_test 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    BEGIN
   IF :NEW.cur_pgm_name = 'LSN' 
   AND :NEW.nxt_pgm_name ='MD' 
   AND :NEW.file_status='RD' THEN 
    INSERT INTO ac1_control_test 
    (FILE_NAME, FILE_PATH,FILE_STATUS,CUR_PGM_NAME,NXT_PGM_NAME)
    VALUES 
   (:NEW.FILE_NAME, :NEW.FILE_PATH,:NEW.FILE_STATUS,:NEW.CUR_PGM_NAME,'MD_MPS');   
END IF;
END ac01_control_trigg;
```

when i am trying to insert into the table i am getting an error below!

```
ORA-04098: trigger 'CNGDB18.AC01_CONTROL_TRIGG' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

could anybody please help?

also when i compile the trigger in Toad,i am getting compile errors as below:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/65     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW_FILE_STATUS'
```

but what is the wrong with this?
and what does this error mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: Now that we see the message, the solution is easy :)

Use 
`:NEW.file_status='RD'` instead of
`:new_file_status='RD'`

---

Your trigger object is invalid (there is a problem with the code).

Test this with:

```
SELECT object_name, status
FROM user_objects
WHERE object_name = 'AC1_CONTROL_TRIGG';
```

Should return:
`AC1_CONTROL_TRIGG   INVALID`

You can try the following in `SQL*Plus` to get a description of the error:

```
ALTER TRIGGER ac1_control_trigg COMPILE;

SHOW ERROR TRIGGER ac1_control_trigg;
```

Using TOAD, you can just type these two lines into an editor, select them and use `Editor`>`Execute SQL via SQL*Plus`.

Comment: thanks..i edited my question.but still the problem is not solved:(